# SOCKS5 request from Azure VM

Tags: python-3.x, azure, socks

I have a Python 3 script that makes requests through a SOCKS5 proxy. I want to be able to run this script from an Azure VM. But when the request is being made I get the following error:

```
Not supported proxy scheme SOCKS5
```

I'm running Python 3.5.2 with requests 2.9.1 on an Ubuntu 16.10 LTS VM. I also installed pysocks to have requests works with SOCKS5.

The code that does the request is as follows:

```
server = 'socks5://u:p@proxy.server.com:1080'
proxies = { 'https': server, 'all': None }
response = requests.get(request_url, proxies=proxies)
```

Te script runs fine locally. So it seems that Azure won't allow me to make use of SOCKS5 proxies.

I've also added port 1080 as allowed outbound connection to the networking interface of the VM.

How do I configure my VM in such a way that it will allow SOCKS5 connections from the

Comment: I believe that it's not an issue about Azure IaaS VM.  As I known, Azure VM doesn't has restriction about SOCKS5. E.g. You can run SS which based on SOCKS5 on an Azure Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that installing pysocks isn't enough.

When you use the following command:

```
pip3 install -U requests[socks]
```

It installs the required packages to work properly.

`-U` is the same as `--upgrade`. This flag is also required, without it you still won't be able to connect through SOCKS5.